# preg_match_all with multiple OR conditions

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

Im trying to create a single regex pattern to match a string where 2 fields (separated by a comma) could either be

- a) empty,
- b) a single word, or
- c) 2 words separated by a backslash (\).

This is a log file where position 1 is a source username field and position 2 is a destination user field, but both could be separated with a backslash if domain name is present (domain\username)

I've tried everything I can think of and can get 2 out of 3 to match, but not all conditions. Below are the possible variants that this string could be in. (something1 and something2 are known patterns that occur before and after this condition)

> something1,,,something2
>
> something1,,dstuser,something2
>
> something1,,dstdomain\dstuser,something2
>
> something1,srcdomain\srcuser,,something2
>
> something1,srcdomain\srcuser,dstdomain\dstuser,something2
>
> something1,srcuser,dstdomain\dstuser,something2
>
> something1,srcuser,dstuser,something2
>
> something1,srcuser,,something2
>
> something1,srcdomain\srcuser,dstuser,something2
>
> something1,srcdomain\srcuser,dstdomain\dstuser,something2

For example, I've tried this:

```
^.*something1,(,|(?J)(?<src_username>[^\\]*),|(?<src_domain>.*?)\\(?<src_username>[^\\]*),).*?,something2*
```

this matches *some* of the time, but I'm curious if this is possible with a single line of regex.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Why not just `explode` on commas then keep what you need?

Comment: I'm trying to run this through an existing parser, and need named groups for src_domain, dst_domain, src_user and dst_user when they exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this regex:

```
(?J)^.*something1,(?:,|(?<src_username>[^,\\]+),|(?<src_domain>[^,\\]+)\\(?<src_username>[^,\\]+),)(?:,|(?<dst_user>[^\\,]+),|(?<dst_domain>[^,\\]+)\\(?<dst_username>[^,\\]*),)something2.*
```

Check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nN3lB9/2)

I am using negated character class `[^,\\]` extensively to not overmatch and stay in the boundaries of a "cell". Also, I make use of `(?:...)` non-capturing groups to not make a mess with the captured groups and helps keep the output clean.

Comment: Works perfectly. so 2 things I was missing:

1) the `?:` at the beginning of the named capture OR condition and 
2) I was mis-using `[^\\]` and instead should have been using `[^,\\]+)`

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, mostly that. I added the note about non-capturing groups into the answer.